Consul DNS and Kubernetes NodeLocalDNS do not work together
I have a problem with configuring ConsulDNS in Kubernetes.
I read the documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/docs/k8s/dns/enable#coredns-configuration
I add this piece to the end of my ConfigMap. I reload all pods, reload all injected pods. Nothing happens. The consul just doesn't appear in /etc/resolv.conf.
I also have NodeLocalDNS. I think the problem is in it because it is responsible for the DNS on the node where the pod is running.
When I add a piece of code with consul to NodeLocalDNS ConfigMap, the Pod does not start, and I get this error. What am I doing wrong? This is how the config files looks.
Consul DNS Service IP: 10.233.53.111
coredns
.:53 {
    errors {
    }
    health {
        lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
      pods insecure
      fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
      prefer_udp
      max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30

    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}
consul {
    errors
    cache 30
    forward . 10.233.53.111
}

nodelocaldns
cluster.local:53 {
    errors
    cache {
        success 9984 30
        denial 9984 5
    }
    reload
    loop
    bind 169.254.25.10
    forward . 10.233.0.3 {
        force_tcp
    }
    prometheus :9253
    health 169.254.25.10:9254
}
consul {
    errors
    cache 30
    forward . 10.233.53.111
}
in-addr.arpa:53 {
    errors
    cache 30
    reload
    loop
    bind 169.254.25.10
    forward . 10.233.0.3 {
        force_tcp
    }
    prometheus :9253
}
ip6.arpa:53 {
    errors
    cache 30
    reload
    loop
    bind 169.254.25.10
    forward . 10.233.0.3 {
        force_tcp
    }
    prometheus :9253
}
.:53 {
    errors
    cache 30
    reload
    loop
    bind 169.254.25.10
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf
    prometheus :9253
}

System info
Kubernetes 1.29.4
Helm chart App version 1.20
Version 1.6.0
Image: hashicorp/consul-k8s-control-plane:1.6.0
/ $ consul info
agent:
        check_monitors = 0
        check_ttls = 0
        checks = 0
        services = 0
build:
        prerelease =
        revision = cddc6181
        version = 1.20.0
        version_metadata =
consul:
        acl = disabled
        bootstrap = true
        known_datacenters = 1
        leader = true
        leader_addr = MY_IP:8300
        server = true
raft:
        applied_index = 7120
        commit_index = 7120
        fsm_pending = 0
        last_contact = 0
        last_log_index = 7120
        last_log_term = 4
        last_snapshot_index = 0
        last_snapshot_term = 0
        latest_configuration = [{Suffrage:Voter ID:795bbdb4-cd1f-d2f9-c8eb-34f380a9ffde Address:MY_IP:8300}]
        latest_configuration_index = 0
        num_peers = 0
        protocol_version = 3
        protocol_version_max = 3
        protocol_version_min = 0
        snapshot_version_max = 1
        snapshot_version_min = 0
        state = Leader
        term = 4
runtime:
        arch = amd64
        cpu_count = 12
        goroutines = 330
        max_procs = 12
        os = linux
        version = go1.22.7
serf_lan:
        coordinate_resets = 0
        encrypted = true
        event_queue = 1
        event_time = 2
        failed = 0
        health_score = 0
        intent_queue = 1
        left = 0
        member_time = 6
        members = 1
        query_queue = 0
        query_time = 1
serf_wan:
        coordinate_resets = 0
        encrypted = true
        event_queue = 0
        event_time = 1
        failed = 0
        health_score = 0
        intent_queue = 0
        left = 0
        member_time = 3
        members = 1
        query_queue = 0
        query_time = 1

NodeLocalDNS pod logs after restart
2024/10/25 02:56:02 [INFO] Starting node-cache image: 1.22.28
2024/10/25 02:56:02 [INFO] Using Corefile /etc/coredns/Corefile
2024/10/25 02:56:02 [INFO] Using Pidfile
2024/10/25 02:56:02 [ERROR] Failed to read node-cache coreFile /etc/coredns/Corefile.base - open /etc/coredns/Corefile.base: no such file or directory
2024/10/25 02:56:02 [INFO] Skipping kube-dns configmap sync as no directory was specified
Listen: listen tcp :53: bind: address already in use

Thanks
